# display website content within an apk app

Tags: android, reactjs, next.js

I have developed an app using `Next.js` and `React`. The client has requested an **Android app**, and I am considering creating an **APK file** that opens our domain. For example, if our domain is example.com, the APK file would open a page like a web browser and shows only example.com. I tried using *Capacitor.js*, but it failed because I’m using SSR of Next.js, which Capacitor.js doesn’t support. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your web app to a PWA (Progressive Web App).  A PWA requires a manifest that basically allows the phone user (iphone or android) to set an icon on her phone desktop that will automatically open your app's website providing the illusion that they are running a native app.

This allows you to leverage your web app as a native app. Here are official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps

I made my password manager a PWA which runs from https://cyapass.com/js/cya.htm

I included the link so you can try it on your phone and see that you can "download" it onto your phone desktop like an app.

You can see the [Mozilla Dev Network installation guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Guides/Installing) to show you how this works.

Good luck.

Comment: pwa is good, but i need an actual app. they want to put it on stores like google play